# CPAN installation prompting "waiting for read lock"

Tags: perl, cpan

I just installed perl and am trying to install CPAN without root privilege.

As I run `cpan App::cpanminus`, I got into an infinite loop echoing `Waiting for read lock on '~/.cpan/FTPstats.yml'`. I tried removing the file and the error persists.

Highly appreciate any solution and thanks in advance!

A snapshot of full log is as follows.

```
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Reading '/home/louis/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Reading '/home/louis/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Tue, 01 Mar 2022 04:17:03 GMT
.............
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.29) available.
  [Currently running version is v2.16]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.


...............................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Tue Mar  1 13:33:09 2022: waiting for read lock on '/home/louis/.cpan/FTPstats.yml' (since Tue Mar  1 13:32:59 2022)
Tue Mar  1 13:33:12 2022: waiting for read lock on '/home/louis/.cpan/FTPstats.yml' (since Tue Mar  1 13:32:59 2022)
```

And some details of access right of `FTPstats.yml`.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 louis louis 0 Mar  1 13:32 /home/louis/.cpan/FTPstats.yml
```

Comment: Sounds like you have another instance of `cpan` running, have you checked for that?

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for your reply. I checked with `fg` and it suggests no another instance of cpan running in background. Could you advise if there is another way to check for alternate instance of `cpan`?

Comment: You need a `ps` listing and perhaps `lsof`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the suggestion. `ps` shows only `sh` and `ps` running, `lsof | grep cpan` returns nothing. Tried running `lsof` but the list is too long for me to attach here.

Comment: What about `lsof /home/louis/.cpan/FTPstats.yml`?

Comment: Also returns nothing.